# como limita só 4 dígitos em python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Faça um programa que permita entrar com o ano de nascimento da pessoa e como
#   ano atual. O programa deve imprimir a idade da pessoa. Não se esqueça de
#   verificar se o ano de nascimento informado é válido.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade?cb=1

Answer (score -3):

````
ano_nasc = input("Digite o ano de nascimento: ")
ano_atual = input("Digite o ano atual: ")

idade = int(ano_atual) - int(ano_nasc)
print("{} anos.".format(idade))```

Ex: ano_nasc = 2005
    ano_atual = 2022
    >>> 17 anos.
````